# Read file and run command in zsh

Tags: bash, zsh

So I generally create job files with a list of commands in it. Then I execute it like so

```
cat jobFile | while read a; do $a; done
```

Which always works in bash. However, I've just started working in Mac which apparently uses zsh. And this command fails with "no such file" etc. I've tested the job file by running few lines from it manually, so it should be fine.

I've found questions on zsh read inbut they tend to be reading in from variables e.g. $a=('a' 'b' 'c') or echo $a

Thank you for your answers!

Comment: If it's a list of commands, you should just use `. jobFile` in both `bash` and `zsh`. You are probably being bitten by the fact that `zsh` does not perform word-splitting on unquoted parameter expansions by default. If `a="foo bar"`, then `$a` attempts to run a command named `foo bar`, not a command named `foo` with an argument `bar`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @chepner . Could you elaborate? What do you mean just use  `. jobFile` ? Do you mean remove the cat command and use . instead or something else? Could you give an example? Sorry for the noobishness!

Comment: You appear to be assuming that each line of your file is a complete shell command, in which case the file itself is a shell script. `. jobFile` does exactly what you want: it executes each command one after the other, but you let the shell properly parse and evaluate each one, rather than relying on parameter expansion hacks.

Comment: @chepner oh ok I got it now! Thanks! Basically just execute it as a shell script directly. Thank you!

Comment: Just because the Mac uses `zsh` as its default interactive shell, it doesn't mean you have to use it in scripts. Put `#!/bin/bash` at the beginning of the script and it will use `bash`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `bash`, unquoted parameter expansions always undergo word-splitting, so if `a="foo bar"`, then `$a` expands to two words, `foo` and `bar`. As a command, this means running the command `foo` with an argument `bar`.

In `zsh`, parameter expansions to *not* undergo word-splitting by default, which means the same expansion `$a` would produce a single word `foo bar`, treated as the name of the command to execute.

In either case, relying on parameter expansion to "parse" a shell command is fragile; in addition to word-splitting, the expansion is subject to pathname expansion (globbing), and you are limited to simple commands and their arguments. No pipes, lists (`&&`, `||`), or redirections allowed, as *everything* will be treated as the command name and a sequence of arguments.

What you want in *both* shells is to simply treat your job file as a shell script, which can be executed in the current shell using the `.` command:

```
. jobFile
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you executing it in such a cumbersome way? Assuming `jobFile` is a file holding a sequence of bash commands, you can simply run it as

```
bash jobFile
```

If it contains a sequence of zsh commands, you can likewise run it as

```
zsh jobFile
```

If you follow this approach, I would however reflect in the name of the job file, what shell it is intended for, i.e.

```
bash jobFile.bash
zsh jobFile.zsh
```

and, if you write a job file so that it is supposed to be compatible with either shell, I would name it `jobFile.sh`.